# echo do_shortcode just prints the shortcode name and not its content

Tags: shortcode

I have this code:

```
<div id="order_form">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[order_form]'); ?>
</div>
```

And my shortcode:

```
<?php

add_shortcode('order_form', 'order_form');
function order_form(){
    return "hello!!";
}
```

But this simply prints out

```
[order_form]
```

Why is that?

Comment: Where do you have the code that adds the shortcode?

Comment: I added your code in functions.php it works fine!!! your code is fine. Please brief a little bit. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment yet - So I will do my best for providing an answer until i get enough rep -

```
 function add_my_shortcode(){
     $content = "Habba";
     return $content;
 }
 add_shortcode('yourShortcodeName', 'add_my_shortcode');
```

I have been doing it like this for a long time, and never had any problems - have you written this code in a file that executes early? 
like functions.php, or have you put it in a template? 
I can't see anything else there could be wrong with your code?

Comment: his code is perfect and works fine. Just we need to know where he places his code. Have any difference between your code and his code :)

Comment: This is why i wanted to comment - His code looks fine - and like i said, I couldn't find anything wrong with it, and asked where he has put it - The code is there to be an easier example of how it works, I don't personally like having the same name for the shortcode and the function. c",)